# parsing [Object] return .load jquery from php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, load

I have this :

```
 p['record_id'] = 2;
 $('#trcode').val($(this).load('url_to_PHP_methode',p,function(str){}));
```

The value returned from PHP method is like this -> `"Just String"`

In firebug, there is correct response value, `"Just String"`, but in text input with ID `#trcode` it shows `[object Object]`.

So, my question is: How to show the correct return value just like Firebug `"Just String"`?

Answer (score 0):

[`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is for loading content into an element, it *returns* the jQuery object (for chaining), which is why you see the `"[object Object]"` string you do now.

Instead, what you want is to use [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and use the response, like this:

```
$.get('url_to_PHP_methode', function(str) {
  $('#trcode').val(str);
});
```

Comment: now the problem is, when I ubmit the form the value of text input #trcode is empty, I check in firebug when I call the function tht i made before is still empty, any suggestion nick ?

Comment: @Neutron - AJAX operations take a bit of time to complete, so you can't do this and submit instantly, you'd need to submit *after* the `.val()` call in the callback function above.  The `$.get()` method fires an AJAX request, and *when it comes back* the value gets populated.  The reason is the server responding takes some time.

Comment: nick, sorry for disturbing u, I found the problem, tnx brother work now, GBU

Comment: @Neutron - welcome! be sure to accept answers to resolved questions via the check-mark beside the one that best helped :)